# #if define string comparison for preprocessor directive

Tags: c, pointers, directive, string-comparison, preprocessor

I'm trying to define an array with preprocessor directives to have variable size. This array is filled depending of #define :

```
#define PORTA                (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)
#define EXP_GPIO0_PORT        PORTA
#define EXP_GPIO0_PIN         0
```

I want to fill the array with :

```
const uint8_t PortAGpiosPortpinUsed[] =
{
    #if EXP_GPIO0_PORT == PORTA
    EXP_GPIO0_PIN,
    #endif
}
```

As PORTA is a pointer, the compiler (GCC) doesn't allow this preprocessor syntax. Is there any solution to get it working ?
Thanks
Syl

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but you should understand that preprocessor work is done *before* compilation or run time, so no compile or run time information is available to it.

Comment: The preprocessor doesn't work like that. Either have another macro (`#define EXP_GPIO0_PORT_IS_PORTA 1`, otherwise undefiend) or do it at runtime

Comment: if `PORTA` is defined by another macro as an integer it works... preprocessor can only compare integers.

Comment: can't compare two constants that are equal in preprocessor ? all expressions are constants. "PORTA" in that case is just a constant address. Both sides are same expression. Can't be at runtime, I need to optimize it as much as possible and preferably scalable...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work:

```
#ifdef PORTA 
#define ADDRESS               (*(PORT_t *) 0x0400)

#define EXP_GPIO0_PORT        ADDRESS
#define EXP_GPIO0_PIN         0
#endif

const uint8_t PortAGpiosPortpinUsed[] =
{
    #ifdef PORTA
    EXP_GPIO0_PIN,
    #endif
}
```

Of course this expects that `PORTA` is previously defined